# JSP Redirect illegal state exception

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have the code below, everything works find till i try to redirect back to the login page where i get the following error: illegal state exception.

I have read that this could be because the response is being committed already, but i cannot see where. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div id="questionContainer">
    <form method="POST">
        <%  
        for (int ques = 1; ques < 56; ques++) {
            try {
                if (iterate.hasNext()) {
                    String[] row = (String[]) iterate.next();
                    if (row[0].equals("1")) {
                        out.println("<div class='trigger' name='trigger" + ques + "'>");
                        out.println("<h2 class='page-header'>Question " + ques + "</h2>");
                        out.println("<p id='question'>" + row[1] + "</p><br/>");
                        out.println("<p id='ansA'><input type='radio'  name='answer" + ques + "' value='A' checked>" + row[2] + "</p>");
                        out.println("<p id='ansA'><input type='radio' name='answer" + ques + "' value='B' >" + row[3] + "</p>");
                        out.println("<p id='ansA'><input type='radio' name='answer" + ques + "' value='C' >" + row[4] + "</p>");
                        out.println("<p id='ansA'><input type='radio' name='answer" + ques + "' value='D' >" + row[5] + "</p><br/>");
                        out.println("</div>");
                    } else if (row[0].equals("2")) {
                        out.println("<div class='trigger'  name='trigger" + ques + "'>");
                        out.println("<h2 class='page-header'>Question " + ques + "</h2>");
                        out.println("<p id='question'>" + row[1] + "</p><br/>");
                        out.println("<p id='ansA'><input type='radio'  name='answer" + ques + "' value='A'checked>" + row[2] + "</p>");
                        out.println("<p id='ansA'><input type='radio' name='answer" + ques + "' value='B'>" + row[3] + "</p>");
                        out.println("<p id='ansA'><input type='radio' name='answer" + ques + "' value='C'>" + row[4] + "</p>");
                        out.println("<p id='ansA'><input type='radio' name='answer" + ques + "' value='D'>" + row[5] + "</p>");
                        out.println("<p id='ansA'><input type='radio' name='answer" + ques + "' value='E'>" + row[6] + "</p><br/>");
                        out.println("</div>");
                    } else if (row[0].equals("3")) {
                        out.println("<div class='trigger'  name='trigger" + ques + "'>");
                        out.println("<h2 class='page-header'>Question " + ques + "</h2>");
                        out.println("<p id='question'>" + row[1] + "</p><br/>");
                        out.println("Answer: <p id='ansA'><input type='text' name='answer" + ques + "'</p><br/><br/>");
                        out.println("</div>");
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        %>
    </form>

    <button type="button" id="Next" name="Next">Next</button>  <button type="submit" value="submited" class="submitBtn" id="Submit" name="Submit">Submit</button>

</div>


 <script>

    var $curCount = 1;

    $(document.getElementsByName("trigger" + $curCount)).show();

    $(document.getElementById("Next")).click(function () {
        $(document.getElementsByName("trigger" + $curCount)).hide();
        $curCount++;
        $(document.getElementsByName("trigger" + $curCount)).show();
        if ($curCount > 55)
        {
            //$(document.getElementsByName("trigger" + $curCount)).hide();
            $curCount = 1;
            $(document.getElementsByName("trigger" + $curCount)).show();
            //window.alert("in loop" + $curCount);

            $(document.getElementsByName("Submit")).show();

        }
    });


    <% if (request.getParameter("Submit") != null && request.getParameter("Submit").equals("submited")) {

            ArrayList listAnswers = new ArrayList();
            for (int ques = 1; ques < 56; ques++) {

                String s = request.getParameter("answer" + ques);
                listAnswers.add(s);
            }
             con.writePAQuestions("test", listAnswers);   
             response.sendRedirect("main.jsp");

        }

    %>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea why this is causing the error. However i bypassed it by using the following in the jsp tags:

```
out.println("window.location='login.jsp';");
```